# How to count total child records of a list of parent records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Team and Player. Players belong to Teams and Teams have_many Players.

If I have an array of teams returned as current_user.teams, how can I count the total number of players on all those teams?

I tried doing the following:

```
current_user.teams.collect { |team| team.players }.count
```

But that just counts the number of teams as each array of team.players is stored as one row in the current_user.teams array even though each record of team.players is an array with many records, each is only being counted once.

How can I break out the team.players arrays to count each player in them in the final count?

Comment: Try `Player.where(team_id: current_user.teams).count`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.collect` runs the block for each element from the array and returns a new array, and hence you should use [sum](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sum)

try,

```
current_user.teams.collect { |team| team.players }.sum
```

note that, if the there are overlapping team players, this would not give count of unique players.

If you have such a use case, then you can try @jvillian's suggestion,

```
Player.where(team_id: current_user.teams).count
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Player.where(team_id: current_user.teams).count
```

I strongly suggest you read the guide on the [ActiveRecord Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

BTW, `collect` iterates the `ActiveRecord::Relation` (or whatever type of `enumerable` you have), which strikes me as unnecessary when you can simply run the query.